# Can't get SCSS/CSS to render in React App no matter what I try for some reason

Tags: css, node.js, reactjs, sass, server-side-rendering

I've been trying to get SCSS/CSS to work on this app for a while still can't. Im not getting an error at this point and I got the css file to compile from scss file but it just wont apply to any component.

https://github.com/ErmanoClaude/React-App.git

Comment: Where is your sass imported?

Comment: Asking people to clone a repo and build it doesn't really work on [SO]. Not only it makes it difficult for anyone trying to help, but it also makes it difficult for anyone having a similar issue to know their issue is similar, hence that any solution to your problem might work in their case. I suggest using codesandbox.io (or similar) to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: You need to import your `sass` file in your component if you want it to work.

Answer (score 0):

was missing the linking to the style sheet the whole time `<link href="/assets/css/styles.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />`